# wirecloud: workspace sources location

Tags: fiware-wirecloud, mashup

I have a local instance of Wirecloud and one of the workspace doesn't work (I can't entry it), so I decided to remove it whit the button for that.

Wirecloud didn't remove it, so I tried of removed it with the Mashup api, but I can't see it.

So, as a last option I tried to remove directly in DB (I deleted on wirecloud_workspace, wirecloud_workspacepreference, wirecloud_userworkspace and wirecloud_tab)...

I still see the workspace in the platform. In filesystem I didn't find anything about workspaces.

I need to remove from other location?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a problem with the search indexes. Try running the `resetsearchindexes` command:

```
$ python manage.py resetsearchindexes -v 2
```